# How to use vue-resource ($http) and vue-router ($route) in a vuex store?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-router, vue-resource, vuex

Before I was getting movie detail from the component's script. The function first check whether the movie ID of the store is same as of the route's param movie ID. If its same then don't get the movie from the server API, or else get the movie from the server API.

It was working fine. But now I am trying to get the movie details from the store's mutation. However I am getting error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$route' of undefined

How to use vue-router `($route)` to access the params and vue-resource `($http)` to get from the server API in vuex store?

store.js:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        movieDetail: {},
    },
    mutations: {
        checkMovieStore(state) {
            const routerMovieId = this.$route.params.movieId;
            const storeMovieId = state.movieDetail.movie_id;
            if (routerMovieId != storeMovieId) {
                let url = "http://dev.site.com/api/movies/movie-list/" + routerMovieId + "/";
                this.$http.get(url)
                    .then((response) => {
                        state.movieDetail = response.data;
                    })
                    .catch((response) => {
                        console.log(response)
                    });
            }
        },
    },
});
```

component script:

```
export default {
    computed: {
        movie() {
            return this.$store.state.movieDetail;
        }
    },
    created: function () {
        this.$store.commit('checkMovieStore');
    },
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To use `$http` or `$router` in your vuex store, you would need to use the main vue instance. Although I don't recommend using this, I'll add what I recommend after answering the actual question.

---

In your `main.js` or wherever you are creating your vue instance like:

```
new Vue({ 
  el: '#app',
  router,
  store,
  template: '<App><App/>',
  components: {
    App
  }
})
```

or something similar, you might also have added the `vue-router` and `vue-resource` plugins too.

Doing a slight modification to this:

```
export default new Vue({ 
  el: '#app',
  router,
  store,
  template: '<App><App/>',
  components: {
    App
  }
})
```

I can now import it in vuex stores like so:

```
//vuex store:
import YourVueInstance from 'path/to/main'

checkMovieStore(state) {
const routerMovieId = YourVueInstance.$route.params.movieId;
const storeMovieId = state.movieDetail.movie_id;
if (routerMovieId != storeMovieId) {
  let url = "http://dev.site.com/api/movies/movie-list/" + routerMovieId + "/";
  YourVueInstance.$http.get(url)
    .then((response) => {
       state.movieDetail = response.data;
     })
     .catch((response) => {
       console.log(response)
     });
  }
}
```

and as the answer by [Austio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1938097/austio) goes, this method should be an `action` as `mutations` are not designed to handle async.

---

Now coming to the recommended way of doing it.

1. Your `component` can access the `route params` and provide it to the `action`.

   ```
    methods: {
      ...mapActions({
        doSomethingPls: ACTION_NAME
      }),
      getMyData () {
        this.doSomethingPls({id: this.$route.params})
      }
    }
   ```
2. The `action` then makes the call through an abstracted API service file ([read `plugins`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html#Writing-a-Plugin))

   ```
    [ACTION_NAME]: ({commit}, payload) {
       serviceWhichMakesApiCalls.someMethod(method='GET', payload)
         .then(data => {
            // Do something with data
         })
         .catch(err => {
            // handle the errors
         })
    }
   ```
3. Your `actions` do some async job and provide the result to a `mutation` .

   ```
    serviceWhichMakesApiCalls.someMethod(method='GET', payload)
         .then(data => {
            // Do something with data
            commit(SOME_MUTATION, data)
         })
         .catch(err => {
            // handle the errors
         })
   ```
4. `Mutations` should be the only ones to modify your `state`.

   ```
    [SOME_MUTATION]: (state, payload) {
       state[yourProperty] = payload
    }
   ```

---

**Example**
A file which contains a list of endpoints, you might need it if you have different stages of deployment which have different api endpoints like: test, staging, production, etc.

```
export const ENDPOINTS = {
  TEST: {
    URL: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1',
    METHOD: 'get'
  }
}
```

And the main file which implements `Vue.http` as a service:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { ENDPOINTS } from './endpoints/'
import { queryAdder } from './endpoints/helper'
/**
*   - ENDPOINTS is an object containing api endpoints for different stages.
*   - Use the ENDPOINTS.<NAME>.URL    : to get the url for making the requests.
*   - Use the ENDPOINTS.<NAME>.METHOD : to get the method for making the requests.
*   - A promise is returned BUT all the required processing must happen here,
*     the calling component must directly be able to use the 'error' or 'response'.
*/

function transformRequest (ENDPOINT, query, data) {
  return (ENDPOINT.METHOD === 'get')
      ? Vue.http[ENDPOINT.METHOD](queryAdder(ENDPOINT.URL, query))
      : Vue.http[ENDPOINT.METHOD](queryAdder(ENDPOINT.URL, query), data)
}

function callEndpoint (ENDPOINT, data = null, query = null) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    transformRequest(ENDPOINT, query, data)
      .then(response => { return response.json() })
      .then(data => { resolve(data) })
      .catch(error => { reject(error) })
  })
}

export const APIService = {
  test () { return callEndpoint(ENDPOINTS.TEST) },
  login (data) { return callEndpoint(ENDPOINTS.LOGIN, data) }
}
```

The queryAdder in case it is important, I was using this to add params to the url.

```
export function queryAdder (url, params) {
  if (params && typeof params === 'object' && !Array.isArray(params)) {
    let keys = Object.keys(params)
    if (keys.length > 0) {
      url += `${url}?`
      for (let [key, i] in keys) {
        if (keys.length - 1 !== i) {
          url += `${url}${key}=${params[key]}&`
        } else {
          url += `${url}${key}=${params[key]}`
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return url
}
```

Comment: I used a variable to refer to the main vue instance in an action. That action gets called during the created hook of a component. At that time, the reference to main vue instance is not available, which leads to an exception.

Comment: This happens only if that component happens to be first one loaded on that route, when user click on browser reload button. If the app is already loaded, navigating to that component works fine. Is there any workaround that case?

Comment: Did you try the recommended method that I have added? Using the instance is not a good way to use $http.

Comment: I haven't figured out how to do that. Some of the official examples use store and api service but they used only mocks instead of http requests. Any links available?

Comment: YourVueInstance.$http didn't work but Vue.http works somehow

Comment: I don't exactly remember, Vue.http does work but it wasn't helpful in one scenario. I'll add an example up here.

Comment: The helper functions I wrote back then too use `Vue.http` I'll post it nevertheless.

Answer (score 2):

So a few things, the $store and $route are properties of the Vue instance, which is why accessing them inside of Vuex instance is not working.  Also, mutations are synchonous what you need are actions

1. Mutations => A function that given state and some arguments mutates the state
2. Action => Do async things like http calls and then commit results to a mutation

So create an action that dispatches the http.  Keep in mind this is pseudocode.

```
//action in store
checkMovieStore(store, id) {
  return $http(id)
    .then(response => store.commit({ type: 'movieUpdate', payload: response })
}

//mutation in store
movieUpdate(state, payload) {
  //actually set the state here 
  Vue.set(state.payload, payload)
}

// created function in component
created: function () {
   return this.$store.dispatch('checkMovieStore', this.$route.params.id);
},
```

Now your created function dispatches the checkMovieStore action with the id, which does the http call, once that is complete it updates the store with the value.

Answer (score 1):

In your vuex store:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.http.post('url',{})
```

Not like in normal vue components:
`this.$http.post(...)`

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend importing [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) on the vuex module (store and submodules), and using it for your http requests

Comment: why? I don't see why `axios` is _always_ the better answer. Can you provide a reason as to why axios is better in this particular circumstance?

Comment: The main reason is the community, you'd find easier to find solutions for problems like this one.

Comment: Maybe, my point is: maybe provide _why_ you recommend another lib to the one the person is actually asking about.

How would you feel if you asked "my car broke down, can somebody please help?" and somebody comes along and says "You should've just gotten a different car".

Comment: And maybe link to something like this: https://medium.com/the-vue-point/retiring-vue-resource-871a82880af4

Answer (score -1):

To access the vue instance in the store use `this._vm`.
But as Amresh advised do not use things like `$router` in vuex