# Vue resource inside Vuex action - "this is null" error

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-resource

I am trying to make a GET call from inside a store action. However my `Vue.http.get()` call throws a `TypeError` "this is null".

I am at a total loss, and I haven't found anyone else with this specific issue elsewhere. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

### Walkthrough

1. User navs to /login/
2. Submits login
3. Authenticated and token received
4. Dispatches action to save token and retrieve profile
5. Error occurs when trying to use `Vue.http` inside action

Note, the token correctly gets stored in state and localStorage.

### Login.vue

```
methods: {
    submit() {
        this.$http.post(
            this.loginEndpoint,
            this.object
        ).then(response => {
            this.$store.dispatch({
                "type": "auth/save",
                "token": response.body.key,
            }).then(() => {
                this.$router.push({name: "home"})
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
    }
}
```

### Store

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import Auth from '../stores/auth.js'


// plugins
Vue.use(Vuex)


export default new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        auth: Auth,
    },
})
```

### auth.js - store module

```
import Vue from 'vue'


export default {
    namespaced: true,

    state: {
        token: null,
        profile: {},
    },

    mutations: {
        setProfile(state, payload) {
            state.profile = payload.profile
        },

        setToken(state, payload) {
            state.token = payload.token
        },
    },

    actions: {
        save: (context, payload) => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const url = "/rest-auth/user/"

                context.commit('setToken', {
                    token: payload.token,
                })

                localStorage.setItem("token", payload.token)

                console.log("get user profile")

                // *** Error below calling Vue.http.get ***
                // TypeError: this is null
                Vue.http.get(url).then(response => {
                    console.log("Profile received")

                    context.commit('setProfile', {
                        profile: response.body,
                    })

                    localStorage.setItem("profile", response.body)
                    resolve()

                }).catch(error => {
                    reject(error)
                })
            })
        },
    },
}
```

### Stack Trace

```
TypeError: this is null
Stack trace:
@webpack-internal:///10:42:9
exec@webpack-internal:///6:1150:21
Client/<@webpack-internal:///6:1179:13
PromiseObj@webpack-internal:///6:200:24
Client@webpack-internal:///6:1143:16
Http@webpack-internal:///6:1400:12
Http[method$$1]@webpack-internal:///6:1431:16
save/<@webpack-internal:///14:112:17
save@webpack-internal:///14:90:20
wrappedActionHandler@webpack-internal:///7:604:15
dispatch@webpack-internal:///7:347:7
boundDispatch@webpack-internal:///7:272:12
submit/<@webpack-internal:///17:100:17
```

Comment: What does your setProfile mutation look like?

Comment: I have updated the question and added more details to the auth.js code. Thanks

Comment: The error only says "this is null"?

Comment: Probably unrelated question: Why do you dispatch the action using "type": "auth/save" and not "type": "save"? I've never seen that before..

Comment: @pymarco can you paste the full error text?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use vue-resource ($http) and vue-router ($route) in a vuex store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42560318/how-to-use-vue-resource-http-and-vue-router-route-in-a-vuex-store?rq=1). That post may solves your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use vue-resource ($http) and vue-router ($route) in a vuex store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42560318/how-to-use-vue-resource-http-and-vue-router-route-in-a-vuex-store)

Comment: @andresgottlieb I've added the stack trace to the bottom of the question. Thanks.

Comment: @ironcladgeek, I am using `Vue.http` the same as done in the answer to that question. That contributor just abstracts things out a bit more than I am doing here.

Comment: @andresgottlieb regarding dispatch "auth/save". From what I've learned that is how to dispatch to a namedspaced store module's action. The closest documentation that I could find is "Binding helpers with namespace" https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/modules.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is specific to my own code and may not contribute generally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that code in my Vue instance was causing the problem. There I was pushing a csrf value to the `X-CSRFTOKEN` header.

I am using Django and DRF. I just switched from `SessionAuthentication` to using `TokenAuthentication` and now have learned that passing the csrf token is not needed.

The code below is from my `main.js` and after removing it the issue is resolved.

### The offending code

```
/* Add the csrf token to the request header */
Vue.http.interceptors.push(function(request, next) {
    let token = this.$cookie.get("csrftoken")
    request.headers.set('X-CSRFTOKEN', token)
    next()
});
```

Exactly why this caused the `TypeError` to be thrown I can't say.

Comment: As this is some code specific problem, it would be best if you close or delete your question - it won't bring any help to anyone as the problem is totally different. It may only cause a confusion.

Comment: You make a good point. Thank you everyone for your time and attention.

Comment: Good luck with Vue! :)