# can't access vue resource inside action vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-resource

hey guys i am trying to do a request inside my action on the vuex side, and i get this error:

```
Cannot read property '$http' of undefined
```

i set my vue-resource this way inside my main.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import App from './App.vue'
import {routes} from './routes';
import {store} from './store/store';
import VModal from 'vue-js-modal'

Vue.use(VModal)
Vue.use(VueResource);
Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

**then on the store:**

```
addStyle(state,newStyleObj) {
    console.log(newStyleObj);
    var vm = this;
    this.$http.post('http://localhost:16339/api/Styles/PostStyle/', newStyleObj)
        .then(response => {
            state.tableStyles = response.body;
            console.log(state.tableStyles)
            console.log(response.body)
        }, error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

any help?

Comment: Try `Vue.$http.post` instead of `this.$http.post`

Comment: still nothing :/

Comment: The state can only be altered in mutations. NOT in actions.

Comment: someone sugested me to do it like this, because actions are assync

Comment: I tried the same last night and got error messages that forced me to do the async fetching in actions which trigger mutations. You cannot do async operations in mutations.

Comment: Here is the same question with proper answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42560318/how-to-use-vue-resource-http-and-vue-router-route-in-a-vuex-store

Answer (score 12):

```
import axios from 'axios'
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: '',
    withCredentials: true,
})

Vue.prototype.$axios = axiosInstance
Vuex.Store.prototype.$axios = axiosInstance
```

This works for me.

Now you can access via `this.$axios` in Vue and Vuex.

Answer (score 6):

You can access Vue instance from the store using this._vm.

```
this._vm.$http.post()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proper explanation of the problem that `$http` is not accessible within vuex https://stackoverflow.com/a/42571288/6355502

The state can only be altered in mutations. NOT in actions. Just commit a mutation from inside of the action to alter the state.

I tried the same last night and got error messages that forced me to do the async fetching in actions which trigger mutations. You cannot do async operations in mutations and you cannot alter the state in actions, so you have to split the code.

```
// in actions
addStyle ({ commit, state }, newStyleObj) {
    console.log(newStyleObj);
    var vm = this;
    this.$http.post('http://localhost:16339/api/Styles/PostStyle/', newStyleObj)
        .then(response => {
            commit("setTableStyles", response.body);
            console.log(state.tableStyles)
            console.log(response.body)
        }, error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}

// in mutations
setTableStyles(state, payload){
state.tableStyles = payload; // or state.tableStyles.push(...payload) if tableStyles is an Array 
}
```

Comment: so where i put my request?

Comment: on the component side, then it should call the mutation that calls the action?

Comment: can you make a clean example of how you do the thing i am trying to?

Comment: your solution doesn't change my issue, i can't access vue-resource, that is my problem

Comment: The example is not perfect. Please look at the vuex docu for the proper mutation calling from into an action.

Comment: i say it again, it has nothing to do with the mutation calling inside action, it has to do with vue-resource, i can't access this.$http

Comment: There is no `this.$http` inside the vuex-file. The `this` variable in vuex functions does not have the `$http` attribiute. If that is your problem you can solve it through requesting the data inside of a component and call the mutation from there.

Comment: exactly, is there no way to have access to it inside the vuex file?

Comment: Maybe you can send the `$http` object as a payload property.

Here is a complex answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42571288/6355502

Answer (score 1):

Outside vue instance (`store` in this case) use `Vue.http` (without the dollar sign), inside instance use `this.$http`.

You can find more on [github](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/master/docs/http.md).

Comment: Or this._vm.$http.get... in any vuex action which avoids having to import the Vue instance in every time

Answer (score 0):

access to axios with `Vue.prototype.$http`

```
login({commit}, loginFormData) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                commit('auth_request');
                Vue.prototype.$http({url: '/user/login', data: loginFormData, method: 'POST'})
                    .then(resp => {
                        const token = resp.data.data.token;
                        const user = resp.data.data.profile;
                        localStorage.setItem('token', token);
                        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
                        Vue.prototype.$http.defaults.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;
                        this.state.user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')) || '';
                        this.state.token = localStorage.getItem('token') || '';
                        commit('auth_success', {token, user});
                        resolve(resp)
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        commit('auth_error');
                        localStorage.removeItem('token');
                        localStorage.removeItem('user');
                        reject(err)
                    })
            })
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Accessing vue Properties by this way  `this._vm.$yourDesiredPropertyName`
For example `this._vm.$http` etc
It worked for me .
You can access all the properties which are properly registered to vue instance