# How can I use vue-logger in the vuex store?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I cannot get vue-logger to work in my Vuex store file(s)

I would like to use vue-logger in my Vuex store file (and modules). However, I keep getting the error: `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'info' of undefined"` when I execute a statement like `"Vue.log.info(....)"`.

I had a similar problem with using "this.$http.get" in the store file, but that works now by using the "Vue.http.get" (as explained in this [StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42560318/how-to-use-vue-resource-http-and-vue-router-route-in-a-vuex-store#42571288)).
However, "`this.$log.info`" does not work (for reasons obvious to me now, as in the store I am outside of the vue instance), but neither does `"Vue.log.info"`.

How can I use vue-logger in the store?

Comment: try [this](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/1399#issuecomment-449972993)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `Vue.$log.info`.

Notice the extra **$** before `log`.

Comment: That works! Thank you! (and why didn't I think if trying that...?)